# Is there a Google App Engine equivalent that lets you use SOAP with Java and is free or a GAE supported SOAP library?

Tags: java, web-services, google-app-engine, soap

It's crucial for us to use SOAP and we don't want to have to attempt rewrite this application in python, so we are looking for alternatives to  Google App Engine that are free or SOAP java libraries that are supported by GAE.

Comment: You need SOAP between a client and GAE, or between GAE and somewhere else ? They are available.

Comment: Between GAE and somewhere else.

Comment: what do you mean by google app engine equivalent?

Comment: Could you clarify if you want how to get SOAP to work in GAE or if you want to use another PAAS platform ?

Comment: @RomainHippeau Sorry, I didn't state the question very well. I rewrote it.

Comment: @PeterRecore please help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585406/how-to-build-a-soap-server-and-client-in-app-engine-using-android-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring WS is nice and I believe you can pick from JIBX, JAXB, or XStream.  XStream should work fine in GAE, but I don't know about JIBX as it uses bytecode manipulation.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/

Comment: please help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585406/how-to-build-a-soap-server-and-client-in-app-engine-using-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

JAX-WS. It's in JDK6.

Comment: what? Jax-ws is listed as not supported by GAE. Please explain.